# Ruby shell execution using %x not working

Tags: ruby

I'm using `uname -n` as an example.  I've tried other shell commands, using the full pathname to the shell command, and I used other delimiters, such as `%x( )` and `%x[ ]`.

```
$ uname -n
my-server
$ which env
/usr/bin/env
$ which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
$ irb
2.2.1 :001 > %x{uname -n}
 => "my-server\n" 
2.2.1 :002 > exit
$ cat ET.rb

    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

    %x{uname -n}

$ ruby ET.rb
$ ### !!!?!?!?  I'm expecting "my-server"
```

Comment: Try `%x({uname -n})`. To execute that in shell use `()` brackets

Comment: `%x{whatever}` runs the shell command and **returns the stdout output of that command as a string**. What you need is to print that string (for example using `puts`).

Answer (score 1):

In IRB, it will show the results of any Ruby statements you feed it. But if in a Ruby script, you should use `puts` or `print` method to print something out:

```
puts %x{uname -n}
```

or:

```
print %x{uname -n}
```

Comment: Thank you... Just adding "puts" was the correct answer